# proving root of limit for root of function

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, radicals

I'm trying to prove:
if  $\lim _{x\to x0}\:f\left(x\right)=\:L$ then $\lim _{x\to x0}\sqrt{f\left(x\right)}=\:\sqrt{L}$ for $L\ge 0$.

I think i've proved it well for $L=0$, saying $\varepsilon$ is $\varepsilon^2$, 
but i'm not sureץ Need and idea how to prove it for $L>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L>0$ . Then $|\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{L}|= \frac{|f(x)-L|}{\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{L}} \le \frac{|f(x)-L|}{\sqrt{L}} $

It follows that $\lim _{x\to x0}\sqrt{f\left(x\right)}=\:\sqrt{L}$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just can't see why does it follows...
Can you please explain?

Comment: This follows from $ |\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{L}| \le \frac{|f(x)-L|}{\sqrt{L}}$  and the squeeze Theorem.